# Mapfish quickstart database unavailable

Tags: database, mapfish

I am trying to complete [MapFish quickstart tutorial](http://www.mapfish.org/doc/2.2/quickstart.html) and now I need to connect to the MapFish quickstart database. The problem appears when I replace the database URL address (`sqlalchemy.url`) in `development.ini` with the connection string given in the instruction (*Creating a web service* part). Once it's done my app keeps displaying the error that informs me the database is not available:

> OperationalError: (OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "www.mapfish.org" (192.30.252.154) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "www.mapfish.org" (192.30.252.153) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? None None

My question is: does anyone know how the database should look like?

I would like to create that database locally and put all required data in it, but I need it's complete schema and all the data it should contain in order to do that.